# Trigger $scope.$watch on angular component

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have this component that works just fine.
It does utc->local and local->utc conversion (required by app logic).

In the model, dates are always in utc, but for display they dates need to be displayed in local time, when changed in UI, the model will have the utc converted date.

$scope.$watch works as expected - when a user tries to change date.

The only problem is that - if user decides no to change date, this  $scope.$watch **will not be fired**, and there will not be any conversion.

What can I do in this situation?

**Angular/TypeScript component:**

```
class RsDateTimeController {
    value: Date;
    displayValue: Date;

    static $inject = ["$scope"];

    constructor($scope: ng.IScope) {
        $scope.$watch(
            "$ctrl.displayValue",
            (newValue: Date, oldValue: Date) => {
                if (newValue != oldValue) {
                    this.value = Utility.toUtcDate(newValue);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    $onInit() {
        if (this.value) {
            this.displayValue = Utility.toLocalDate(this.value);
        }
    }

}

class RsDateTimeComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    public bindings: any;
    public controller: any;
    public template: string;

    constructor() {
        this.template = "<input type='datetime-local' class='form-control' ng-model='$ctrl.displayValue'>";
        this.bindings = {
            value: "="
        };
        this.controller = RsDateTimeController;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
app.component("rsDatetime", new RsDateTimeComponent());

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>@("Status Date".T())</label>
        <rs-datetime ng-if="vm.woChangeStatus" value="vm.woChangeStatus.StatusDate"></rs-datetime>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using Angular 2.0? I ask because in 2.0 `$watch` is no longer necessary.

Comment: Why don't you initialize this.value to some default value? So, if the user doesn't change a date, it will display the default.

Comment: frishi, angular 1.5.хх

Comment: Hoyen, I do, initialize it, but as I said all date values in the model are in UTC format, in $onInit they will be converted to local time for display. BUT, if user doesnt change the date in that component, the  $scope.$watch is not fired, and the date displayed in local time will be sent to the model as local time, the conversion inside $scope.$watch doesn happen.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly the function of `$watch`, it will fire the listener callback you specified. When the user does not make any changes, the model is not dirty, and hence the `$watch` does not fire.

There are 2 things in play here: when the model changes, the view should be updated and when the view changes, the underlying model should be updated.

*Updated Answer*

Based on the conversation in the comments, I would write a filter that simply does the conversion (UTC -> local display value) and use it in the UI.

That is a much cleaner approach, and does not ask you to jump through hoops of converting the display values if the user makes no changes. Your component, then, will only convert if the user initiates change, which it already does.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You see this code: this.value = Utility.toUtcDate(newValue); it will execute ONLY if user changes anything in the rs-datetime component. What if he doesnt? I still need this code to be executed.

Comment: I realize that now, I have posted thoughts in an update. Without user triggering an event, there is no way to really know _when_ to do the conversion. I assume you persist this model somewhere, and that could be where you could perform the conversion.

Comment: I have all the conversions in place. I am asking about the component. In my model all dates, as I already mentioned are in UTC format. The component DOES the conversion: utc->local for display, and local->utc when the value is changed in UI. The component does that. The question again: is how to make the component to run whats inside $scope.$watch BUT without user changing the value. Maybe there is a way to emulate date time change without user intervention?

Comment: O.K. in that case, I would write a filter that simply does the conversion (UTC -> local display value) and use it in the UI. That is a much cleaner approach, and does not ask you to jump through hoops of converting the display values if the user makes no changes. Your component, then, will only convert if the user initiates change, which it already does.

Comment: I have a filter for read only views. This component, as you can see is used in forms, where a user must enter date/time.

Comment: So, when the form first loads, does it read values from the model that were saved previously? Or uses some default values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129275/discussion-between-frishi-and-monstro).

Comment: Yes, there is a model behind a form.